# Extent of the Persian Gulf

Tags: geology

Is there a consensus on when the Persian Gulf reached its modern day levels? So far the material I have read says the Persian Gulf attained its present levels around 4000 BCE, but I am not too sure. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question entirely, what level and extent are you exactly talking about?

Comment: @hugovdberg I suspect he means sea levels of the Gulf. It is the only factor I found that matches the 4000 BCE claim.

Answer (score 5):

You are pretty much spot on in terms of the date.  According to the article [Shoreline reconstructions for the Persian Gulf since the last
glacial maximum](http://people.rses.anu.edu.au/lambeck_k/pdf/171.pdf) (Lambeck, 1996) based on models of glacio-hydro-isostatic effects of the end of the last ice age and the article [Early State Formation
in Southern Mesopotamia:
Sea Levels, Shorelines,
and Climate Change](http://www.psu.edu/dept/liberalarts/sites/kennett/djkennett/pdf/Kennett_Kennett2006.pdf) (Kennett and Kennett, 2006) indicate from archaeological observations that at around 6000 years before present (~4000 BCE) that the present shorelines were approximately shaped.  Both articles record an initial inundation of the Tigris-Euphrates delta.

The process is summarised in the image below:

[image]

Image source: [University of California - Santa Barabara](http://emvc.geol.ucsb.edu/2_infopgs/IP2IceAge/ePersGulfFlood.html)